# why doesn't work a href on menu bar?

Tags: javascript

I have downloaded a css/javascript menu but when i put a link with a href;

```
<a href=about.html> About </a>
```

it happens nothing if i click on the 'About' text, the redirecting doesn't work.. You can download the file and try it :

http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2010/02/creating-a-fancy-menu-using-css3-and-jquery/

i have changed .js file but nothing happens.

Comment: caus you are missing the "" for value of the heref

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attributes need to be quoted; use `<a href="about.html">About</a>`.

Also, the code for clicking a menu item is this:

```
// ...

}).click(function(){

    $(this).siblings('li').removeClass('active');

    $(this).addClass('active');

    return false;
})
```

`return false` cancels the event. You need to remove the `return false`; however this will defeat the whole purpose of the menu system you're using. You need to listen to the click event, and show the correct content dynamically.

Comment: thank you so much. and how can i center my menu bar on the page ? its on the left side now.